# How to filter network traffic with BPF(PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER)?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, ebpf

I want to control outcoming traffic with BPF filters and tried the [next example from bpfcc-tools](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bpfcc/-/tree/9a55e766cc76b5fab96eb0b631a37315c02f5269/examples/networking/http_filter) .
But there are two issues:

1. The incoming packets only triggers that BPF code.
2. The example doesn't filter incoming network traffic nevertheless it promises to filter non-HTTP traffic.

I've tried to filter any traffic with the next code:

```
int http_filter(struct __sk_buff *skb) { 
  return 0;
  [...]
```

But it doesn't works either.

1. Please tell me what's wrong with the examples above. Why it don't filter?
2. Is it possible to make a BPF filter based on PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER to control outcoming packets?
3. Can you propose me a way to filter any outcoming network packets with BPF or similar approach?
   I know iptables NFQ could do so. But it doesn't suitable to me due to some reason.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What do you mean by the existing program “doesn't filter, only triggers” the eBPF code? In this example the filtering happens at the socket level on the ingress path, meaning that it will filter what incoming packets are copied to user space for your socket (and logged on the terminal). How are you checking that the packets are “filtered”? For 3. look at the TC egress hook (eBPF as classifiers) to block packets on the egress path.

Comment: I've run the example and found that it just prints appropriate HTTP requests to a terminal. But it doesn't actually filter any other traffic. For example I can open ssh session or ping through interface with that filter.  
I want to write an userspace software which will decide that pass or drop outcoming network packet.

Comment: Ok so yes, this is expected. The tool simply opens a raw socket, and “filters” traffic in the sense that selected traffic is copied to user space, the rest remains on kernel space to be processed by the rest of the IP stack (this does not mean it is dropped). To drop outgoing packets you need to hook on a TC egress classifier. You can probably search for “eBPF firewall” or something along this (most examples might be for incoming packets and use XDP instead of TC though). Returning `TC_ACT_SHOT` from a program attached as a classifier on your interface should drop all the traffic, for example.

Comment: You will also find some generic documentation in the [BPF and XDP Reference Guide](https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/) from Cilium, although it's dense. I can't think of an example project that implements just what you're looking for (some do but are rather complex to dive into).

Comment: I've got it! Thank you for your comments and proposal.

Comment: Anyway, If somebody have other ideas, please let me know. It will be good for some case.